# SSRS 2017 - Drill Down Chart - How to drill-down to the level where only one item will be shown?

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, drilldown

One more SSRS question...
In my Drill Down Chart report I have the multiple levels:

Region \ Program Type \ Program \ Employees

When I drill down to employee level - all the employees appear, from the appropriate Program.
But I also wish to drill down by each individual employee (Stuff). 
(To see the calculations for each one)

Here are my Actions & Scope:

` 
         Scope:

```
   =SWITCH(
Parameters!Scope.Value = "Region", "ProgramType",   
Parameters!Scope.Value = "ProgramType", "Program",
Parameters!Scope.Value = "Program", "Staff"
```

)

Region:
       =SWITCH(

```
Parameters!Scope.Value = "Region", Fields!GLRegionWHID.Value,   
Parameters!Scope.Value = "ProgramType", Fields!GLRegionWHID.Value,
Parameters!Scope.Value = "Program", Fields!GLRegionWHID.Value,
Parameters!Scope.Value = "Staff", Fields!GLRegionWHID.Value
```

)

Program Type:
   =SWITCH(

```
Parameters!Scope.Value = "Region", -1,  
Parameters!Scope.Value = "ProgramType", Fields!EHRProgramTypeWHID.Value,    
Parameters!Scope.Value = "Program", Fields!EHRProgramTypeWHID.Value,
Parameters!Scope.Value = "Staff",Fields!EHRProgramTypeWHID.Value
```

)

Program:

```
=SWITCH(

Parameters!Scope.Value = "Region", -1,  
Parameters!Scope.Value = "ProgramType", -1, 
Parameters!Scope.Value = "Program", Fields!GLProgramWHID.Value,
Parameters!Scope.Value = "Staff", Fields!GLProgramWHID.Value
```

)

`
'Staff' is not a parameter, but the field [GLProgramWHID]
If there is a way to write in SSRS to drill down to each employee - i'd me much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: It's not clear (to me) what the problem is. Can you post screenshots and sample data to help us understand the issue.

Comment: Hi Alan,                                                                                                                         I'll try to describe by providing more details:

Comment: I have                                                                                                             Regions:    R1, R2, R3, R4...   ... etc    Pressing on the one Region (R2, for example) and receiveing

Comment: Programs: P1, P2, P3, P4 ...   ... etc, pressing on (P2 for example) and receiving

Comment: Employees: E1, E2, E3, E4...    E20  etc

Comment: I want to press on the ONE employee graph (E1 - for examle)  and to receive only his name with the calculations, related to this E1 employee only

Comment: ------------ 22     E1       ------------- 65  E2    --------- 45 E5   and if I'll press on E1, I'd like to have     ------------22  E1 graph ONLY

Comment: Just draw images in excel or something and edit your question. Adding to comments is not good practice.